# Regexp extract of the dynamic information from the bash variable using awk or sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

If the value changes, i.e. it could be

```
project-crm-backend-build-pipeline-run-98b6r-slack-notific-8fzvf
```

or

```
backend-build-pipeline-run-aaaaa-test-eeee
```

and I only need to extract the following from both examples above

```
project-crm-backend-build-pipeline-run-98b6r
backend-build-pipeline-run-aaaaa
```

i.e. the only thing that is constant is "pipeline-run", everything else could be changing, so I need to include everything before the pipeline-run and the single token right after the *pipeline-run*

Answer (score 1):

With [Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion):

```sh
$ t='build-pipeline'

$ s='project-crm-backend-build-pipeline-run-98b6r-slack-notific-8fzvf'
$ echo "${s%-${s#*${t}-*-*-}}"
project-crm-backend-build-pipeline-run-98b6r

$ s='backend-build-pipeline-run-aaaaa-test-eeee'
$ echo "${s%-${s#*${t}-*-*-}}"
backend-build-pipeline-run-aaaaa
```

`${s#*${t}-*-*-}` will delete minimally from start of string, matching contents of variable `t` and then till 3rd `-` after.

The remaining string that is obtained is then used (after prefixing with a `-` character) to be deleted from end of string, thus giving the portion required.

With `sed`

```sh
echo "$s" | sed -E 's/('"$t"'-run-[^-]+).*/\1/'
```

Both these solution assume contents of variable `t` don't have characters that can effect the expansion/regex.

Answer (score 0):

okay this is my working solution, just in case someone gets into the same issue

```sh
TEKTON_PIPELINE_NAME=build-pipeline
echo $POD_NAME | awk -v search="[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$TEKTON_PIPELINE_NAME-run-[a-z0-9]+" 'match($0, search) { print substr( $0, RSTART, RLENGTH )}'
```